# How to specify requirements for versions of dependencies for ocaml dune projects?

Tags: ocaml, dependency-management, ocaml-dune

Say I run `dune init proj hello_world`, then modify the `bin/dune` and `bin/main.ml` files so that a new dependency `foobar` is in use.

The `bin/dune` file now:

```
(executable
 (public_name hello_world)
 (name main)
 (libraries hello_world foobar))
```

**1. How can I specify that the `foobar` library should have a certain exact version?**

**2. If we know that the `foobar` library uses semantic versioning, how could I specify that any version with the major version as 3 is required?**

ocaml version 4.14.0
dune version 3.6.1

Answer (score 2):

Package dependencies for a project are specified in the `dune-project` file, see https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html#package

A default `dune-project` file is generated by `dune init proj ...`.

To add a dependency with a version constraint, add a line in the `depends` field like

```
(depends 
  (foobar (>= 3))
```

Note that this is needed in addition to specifying which libraries the executable component depends on, which is what you have on the `bin/dune` file.